# Error Undefined en descarga de archivos con response()->download en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

Estoy haciendo un aplicativo para la gestión de documentación por lo que esta debe permitir subir y descargar archivos.
El almacenamiento de los archivos se realiza perfectamente, entiendo que Laravel crea una especie de enlaces simbólicos hacia las carpetas que este maneja para que el navegador pueda acceder a los archivos que necesite.

Esta es la configuración

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'covers' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/covers'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'files' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/files'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],


    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('covers') => storage_path('app/covers'),
        public_path('files') => storage_path('app/files'),
    ],
```

Los archivos los estoy almacenando directamente en el disco public (por ahora) como se muestra a continuación. Esta función se ejecuto por medio de una petición POST

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $file=$request->file('file');
        $uploadFolder = 'public';

        if($file){

            $file_path=time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = Storage::putFileAs($uploadFolder, new File($file), $file_path);
            $archivo = Archivos::create([
                'nombre' => $file_path,
                'path' => $path,
                'seccion' => $request->seccion,
                'tipo' => $request->tipo
            ]);

            return response()->json($archivo,200);
        }

        return response()->json(["message" => "Seleccione un archivo"]);
    }
```

La función de descarga es la siguiente, accedo a esta por una petición GET.

```
public function getFileById($id)
    {
        $archivo = Archivos::find($id);
        if (is_null($archivo)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Archivo no encontrado'], 404);
        }

        $fileName = $archivo->nombre;
        $filePath = $archivo->path;

        if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($fileName)) {

            $pathToFile = public_path('storage/' . $fileName);

            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            ];

            // return Storage::download($pathToFile, $fileName, $headers);
            return response()->download($pathToFile, $fileName, $headers);
            // return response()->json(['message' => $filePath], 200);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Archivo no encontrado'], 404);
        }

    }
```

El cual como ven también he tratado de ejecutarlo con `Storage::download` pero me da error, No encuentra la ruta. Con response al menos si devuelve un status 200 pero no descarga nada y da error undefined.

esta es la imagen de lo que retorna, parece que el pdf esta codificado de alguna manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no he encontrado un problema parecido, pensé que era cuestión de los headers pero nada me resulta. Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

Comment: Prueba `return Storage::disk('public')->download($fileName);`

Comment: También, ahora que veo que usas postman, selecciona la acción "Enviar y descargar" en vez de sólo "Enviar". Según la [doc](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/responses/)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ muchas gracias por el comentario sobre como manejar la consulta en postman, me hizo notar que en el frontEnd estaba utilizando un header incorrecto para manejarla respuesta de la API

Comment: Vale. Si lograste resolverlo, por favor publica una respuesta con la solución